# sorting dict() and Orderedict()

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key-value, ordereddictionary

I have a question.
L have ordereddictionary like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
d[23] = 2
d[45] = 2
d[5] = 1
```

I want to sorting.I want to find biggest value (2) and return the key of this value (45 or 23)
if there is a 2 biggest values (23:2 and 45:2) then show the item with biggest key(45:2)
can someone help me?

Comment: So you want some sort of data structure that gives you the maximum of a tuple (value, key) for example `(2, 45)`?

Comment: Why do you need an OrderedDict?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```
max(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1,0))
```

This returns the max `(key, value)` based on value and if the value is duplicated then based on key as asked.